# Handling Uploads on a Django Site Behind a Load Balancer

Tags: django, file-upload, load-balancing

I have a small- to medium-sized Django project where the client has been forced to change hosts. The new host convinced them they definitely needed a couple of web servers behind a load balancer (and to break the database off to a third server). I have everything ported over to the new setup, but I can't make it live yet as I'm not sure what's the best way to handle file uploads on the site as they will only get pushed up to the server the user is currently connected to. Given the three servers (counting the db which could double as a static file server if I had to), what's the cleanest and easiest way to handle this situation?

Comment: Wouldn't you have a shared filesystem between servers and you would have all web workers writing to it, so it wouldn't really matter?

Comment: It's two separate boxes right now. I've never had to handle this before, so I'm not sure-- how would a shared filesystem work?

Comment: Something like a nfs? How are you serving static right now?

Comment: I'm serving them on an Apache/ Nginx setup on a single box at the old host, so it's not an issue. The new host isn't live yet.

Comment: Answer to a similar question on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/185355/handling-user-uploads-to-a-web-server-cluster. Or use something like S3 + django-storages, if that's an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution which has some latency though and is not scalable beyond several servers - use rsync between hosts. Simply add it to cron to do upload dir sync both ways, also sticky session would help here - so that uploader would see their file as available immediately, and other visitors will be able to get the file after the next rsync completes.

This way you also get a free backup.

```
/usr/bin/rsync -url --size-only -e "ssh -i servers_ssh.key" user@server2:/dir /dir
```

(you'll have to have this in cron on both servers)

Comment: Yeah, this was the best I could come up with as well for a simple solution. Thanks.